# How has QAnon narrative being affected by Jan 6, the social media bans, and Trump's leaving office?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, conspiracy-theories, qanon

I haven't heard much about QAnon since Trump's leaving office.  It seems between the backlash and banning that came after Jan 6 and Trump's leaving office without any of the major QAnon predictions having come to pass, the QAnon narrative would be suffering.

I'm wondering about two related things.  First how does QAnon narrative explain Trump's removal from office and failure to 'out' any of the deep state?  Second, how have recent events affected overall support of QAnon?  Is it seeing less activity and support without a Trump presidency and petering out, or is it still roughly as strong and active as it always has been?

Comment: I'm not sure that "what does QAnon say" is any more answerable than "what does Antifa say" or "what does BLM say" about something. As none of these is an organization that can speak on a single voice. Sure a quick search finds some media articles about "QAnon in disarray" after Biden taking office etc.

Comment: Given this question is "How has QAnon been affected by reality?" I don't think it's answerable

Comment: @JSLavertu: apparently Q hasn't posted anything since December, but that didn't stop followers from making their own new theories https://www.wcbe.org/post/why-qanon-survives-after-trump And Q never really posted clear messages anyway, as I understand it.

Comment: @JSLavertu: according to a [study (oreprint)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.08750) the Drops were apparently not written by a single person either.

Comment: The same conclusion is drawn in another analysis https://www.france24.com/en/live-news/20210117-swiss-text-sleuths-unpick-mystery-of-qanon-origins

Comment: @Fizz Very interesting article, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Some 538 analysis https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/what-comes-next-for-qanon-followers/ and  https://fivethirtyeight.com/videos/confidence-interval-qanon-is-not-going-anywhere/

Comment: You mean aside from [doubling down](https://www.newsweek.com/qanon-march-trump-president-1567525) on the crazy?

Comment: Isn't Trump's removal just further proof of how powerful the Deep State is? They got to all the judges and election boards to steal the election.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some die-hard QAnon believers have come up with ways to keep believing, e.g. by claiming that [Trump is not only still secretly president, he's also executing enemies of the state by hanging](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-politics/trump-qanon-president-white-house-executions-b1798452.html), or by claiming that [Kamala Harris didn't actually swear on a Bible during her inauguration, hence she's not actually vice-president.](https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2021/jan/22/facebook-posts/kamala-harris-was-sworn-stack-bibles-not-clutch-pu/)

[Others are losing faith, and leaving the movement](https://apnews.com/article/qanon-conspiracy-theory-recovery-4ea47c2966a41b30ae678e5f471f6070).

If you're interested in what comes next for QAnon believers, [here's a news article to read](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/what-comes-next-for-qanon-followers/).